# Polymer doesn't work when installed with Bower

Tags: polymer, bower

Edit: it's working now, I just reinstalled Polymer from scratch. Can't find out what I was doing wrong before.
-.-

I'm testing with one of the [layouts](http://www.polymer-project.org/samples/layout-elements/scaffold-app.html).

When Polymer in installed with Bower layout does not work, console log is given at the end of this msg.(In this case components are placed in /bower_components folder)

But when I just copy-paste /components folder from given [polymer-tutorial](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html) (and point the links in the layout to there) everything works fine.

What am I missing so installation with Bower wont work?

Here is the console log:

> 

```
XHR finished loading: GET "chrome-extension://mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja/content.min.css". content.min.js:1
XHR finished loading: GET "http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.css". loader.js:87
XHR finished loading: GET "http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.css". loader.js:87
XHR finished loading: GET "http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.css". loader.js:87
XHR finished loading: GET "http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-icon-button/core-icon-button.css". loader.js:87
Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at core-menu.Polymer.addListener (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-selector/core-selector.html:273:17)
    at core-menu.Polymer.targetChanged (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-selector/core-selector.html:266:16)
    at core-menu.g.invokeMethod (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:12916)
    at core-menu.g.notifyPropertyChanges (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:11202)
    at Object.Observer.report_ (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:12814)
    at Object.createObject.check_ (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:18305)
    at c (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:5610) observe.js:769
Exception caught during observer callback: TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at core-selector.Polymer.addListener (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-selector/core-selector.html:273:17)
    at core-selector.Polymer.targetChanged (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/core-selector/core-selector.html:266:16)
    at core-selector.g.invokeMethod (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:12916)
    at core-selector.g.notifyPropertyChanges (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/polymer/polymer.js:12:11202)
    at Object.Observer.report_ (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:12814)
    at Object.createObject.check_ (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:18305)
    at c (http://somehost/sites/test/polymer-tutorial-layout/bower_components/platform/platform.js:12:5610)
```

Comment: did everything install successfully when you ran `bower install`?